# swipe tabs with nested fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

Sorry for the long Q!

I have the following code that works fine: click on a button that starts 2 fragments, 1 with a list and the other one showing some data on an item click. As I have several buttons doing the same thing, I am trying to change the code to swipe tabs.

So I have an activity MenuVoice that has a VoicePagerAdapter that implements the fragments.

MenuVoice

```
 public class MenuVoice extends FragmentActivity {
 ...
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager_voice);

    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

    voicePagerAdapter = new VoicePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    voicePagerAdapter.voicePassInt(lang,level);
    voicePagerAdapter.voicePassString(login);
    viewPager.setAdapter(voicePagerAdapter);
```

VoicePagerAdapter

```
 public class VoicePagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
 ...
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int index) {
    Bundle bundle;
    Fragment c = null;
    if (index == 0) {
        c = new VoiceSong_fragment();
```

VoiceSong instantiates 2 fragments, using xml, the 1st fragment that implements the list SongFragment1 and the second one who is supposed to display someting.

And finally I use an interface to communicat between the fragment SongFragment1 and SongFragment2 through fragment VoiceSong.

xml

```
<fragment
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:name="com.example.bernard.speechparole.SongFragment1"
    android:id="@+id/song_fragment1"
    />

<fragment
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:name="com.example.bernard.speechparole.SongFragment2"
    android:id="@+id/song_fragment2"
    />
```

SongFragment1 is crashing on the initialisatio of the comunicator interface:

```
 public class SongFragment1 extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{
...
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

   -->  communicator = (SongCommunicator) getActivity();
```

with the msg:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.bernard.speechparole.MenuVoice cannot be cast to com.example.bernard.speechparole.SongCommunicator
        at com.example.bernard.speechparole.SongFragment1.onActivityCreated(SongFragment1.java:78)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:1794)
```

Is there anything I do wrong? What would you do in that scenario?

Any clue on the error message?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem that is linked to do the communicator interface in a fragment. Apparently this is not authorized?

It means what I do must be separated in its own activity (2 fargments passing data omItemClick)? And then it cannot be inside one swipe tabs?